# How to pass variables to if statement using jade template

Tags: pug

I'm passing `service_type` through jade. Trying to compile with `service_type = 'gas'`.
I tried:

```
- if(#{service_type}=='gas')
p gas
```

I've also tried:

```
- if('#{service_type}'=='gas')
p gas
```

but neither work... How can I check two strings are equals?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it working correctly without the {}

```
-if(service_type=='gas') 
  p gas
```

Comment: Took me forever to figure this out. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6):

You actually also don't need the initial hyphen at the beginning.

```
if (service_type=='gas')
    p gas
```

The above should work just fine also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try it in a following way:

```
-if(#{service_type}=='gas') 
  p gas
```

Because in jade, incorrect spacing can cause errors.